# what maintainable,scalable and modular actually means?

Tags: java, architecture, software-design

What does it mean actually when i read in any article/book that it will make your application maintainable,scalable and modular.

I do have my vague understanding about them but i am am clear what actually they mean. For example :- I heard/read lot of times that mvc architecture
makes app more maintainable,scalable and modular. Here is my understanding :-

**Maintainable :-** If we need to accomodate minor change/ or some defect, its easy to handle that. Also code should be unit testable.
Prior to MVC world, view,controller and model roles were played by servlet. So it is difficult to acoomdodate any change. Also it was difficult 
from unit testing point of view

**Scalable :-** How application responds to increment in user load.

**Modular :-** To me this term looks very abstract. Modularization is about decomposing the application in to the modules which
can be developed by independent teams without affecting each other. Decomposition can be done based on other factors like
reusability, feature wise so that sub team  can work independently, testability.

Now how MVC makes the code modular. Probably becoz team can work independently on views, controller and models.

Please Correct me if i am wrong some where or i have missed any important aspect here

Comment: I feel this question is far too broad for Stack Overflow. There are whole books written on this sort of subject. You need to massively narrow the scope of the question, perhaps focussing on one specific area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Maintainable**: Other than what you have mentioned, a maintainable system also means that doing major changes should not be *much* of a problem (obviously this depends on the size of the change itself). That is, if the client wants to make an overhaul of the entire UI layer, then, doing so would mean that you do not need to rewrite half of your business logic and data layers.
- **Scalable**: Not really. An application scales well if it is able to accommodate an increasing number of users without any major impacts on its ability to perform. If your application handles requests under 10ms for 1000 users but takes 1000ms for 2000, then it might be that your application is not scaling well. Scalability is usually achieved through a clever design will allows clever usage of resources, such as database connections and other mechanisms such as caching, which can reduce the usage of heavy operations.
- **Modular**: Not exactly. An application is modular if it is loosely coupled but tightly coheased. What this means is that modules are independent from each other however, they work well in unison. So, as per my previous example, if you build your application in a modular manner, doing changes in the UI layer, should not affect your business layer, and the same goes the other way round.

As per this statement:

> Now how MVC makes the code modular. Probably becoz team can work
>   independently on views, controller and models.

it is *my opinion* that MVC makes it easier to break the system into modules. That being said, I do not think that if a system does not use MVC then the system is not modular etc. You can encounter applications which where built with the MVC pattern but are a nightmare to maintain, and the same goes the other way round.